# Plot sparsely populated 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

from an iterative image pattern search with decreasing step size I have a 'quality' array. Due to the nature of the search pattern the array is not fully filled. In the first iteration I go with stepsize 10, find the best spot and there search a +-10 XY range to find the true best spot. So most of the array has every 10th slot filled and there is the small 'best' region that is densely filled. Now I want to plot this array and would want the plot to be 'interpolated' where needed by using the data every 10th slot. Now to do my search I initialize the array with a huge value. All my measurements are smaller and later I use the `np.argmin(q)` function. That works fine for searching but for plotting it is bad. The dynamic range of the plot is lost.

Here is an example from an older version of the code that does exhaustive but unnecessarily long search :

[image]

And here is what I get with the optimized search :

[image]

Here is the piece of code that does the plots. (q is the quality array to plot)

```
fig= plt.figure(1)
im= plt.imshow(q[::-1], cmap='rainbow', interpolation='none', extent=[-search_size,search_size,-search_size,search_size])
fig.savefig(pfn(img_fn), bbox_inches='tight')
```

The issue may point back to the initialization of the array. Again as I do a minimum search I do this :

```
q = np.empty(shape=(2*search_size,2*search_size))
q.fill(+1e20)

q_min = 1e20

for xs in range(-search_size,+search_size,search_step):
    for ys in range(-search_size,+search_size,search_step):
        img_shift = np.zeros_like(img)
        img_shift[mom(ys):non(ys), mom(xs):non(xs)] = img[mom(-ys):non(-ys), mom(-xs):non(-xs)]
        d = np.absolute(img_shift - prev_img)[search_size:-search_size,search_size:-search_size]
        q[ys+search_size,xs+search_size] = np.sum(d)
        if q[ys+search_size,xs+search_size] < q_min : q_min= q[ys+search_size,xs+search_size]
        #print '1st iter try : %+3d %+3d %6.3f %6.3f' % ( xs, ys, q[ys+search_size,xs+search_size], q_min)

idxmin = np.argmin(q)
dy,dx = np.unravel_index(idxmin, q.shape)
dx= dx-search_size
dy= dy-search_size
print '1st iter best : dx= %+3d  dy= %+3d' % ( dx , dy )
```

Then follows another loop with `search_step = 1`.

Is it possible to initialize the array i.e. with `NaN` ? Would that allow the minimum search? And/or would it allow the plotter to jump accross undefined entries?

So what's the best way to initialize / plot so that the search works and the plots look good?

Thanks,
Gert

---

Update @Nix G-D

The averaging fails. I first tried code following the recommendation.

```
q_int = pd.DataFrame(q).interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).values
fig= plt.figure(1)
im= plt.imshow(q_int[::-1], cmap='rainbow', interpolation='none', extent=[-search_size,search_size,-search_size,search_size])
```

However the 2D interpolation failed. (at least as indicated by the plot)

[image]

I tried to add code to perform X and Y interpolation.

```
q_int = pd.DataFrame(q).interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).values
q_int = pd.DataFrame(q_intx).interpolate(method='linear', axis=1).values
fig= plt.figure(1)
im= plt.imshow(q_int[::-1], cmap='rainbow', interpolation='none', extent=[-search_size,search_size,-search_size,search_size])
```

But results still were corrupted.

[image]

Best,
Gert

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize the array with NaN easily:

```
shape = (2*search_size, 2*search_size)
q = np.full(shape, np.nan)
```

This can then be searched as normal.  To find the minimum indices ignoring NaNs, you can use `np.nanargmin()`

```
In [12]: np.nanargmin([1,-1,4,float('nan')])
Out[12]: 1
```

To get rid of these NaN values we can use, [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate):

```
q_interpolated = pd.DataFrame(q).interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).values
```

Comment: Update @Nix G-D

The averaging fails. Please see above append to question.